# Basis for a Subspace of V

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a finite dimensional vector space $V$, and a subspace of $V$, say $W$, will every basis for $V$ contain a basis for $W$?

I know that the vectors in the basis of $V$ span $W$, but I'm not sure about linearly independence, can vectors just be thrown away from the set?

Comment: No. Consider $W = \text{span}(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\1 \end{bmatrix})$ and $V = \mathbb{R}^2$. Then the canonical basis for $V$ does not contain a basis for $W$.

Comment: @CatalinZara Is {(0,1), (1,0)} not a basis for both?

Comment: Is $(0,1)$ in $W$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general no, the problem is that the basis for $V$ spans too much to be a basis for its subspace. This may only be true if $dimW = dimV$. Recall that the definition of a basis must be that it is EQUAL to the subspace it is desired to span.

For example, consider a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$, say $span\{(1, 1, 0)\}$. No combination of the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ will be able to span this (span not contain. Of course, it can contain this).

If you mean will every subspace of $W$ in a vector space $V$, every basis for $W$ is however, spanned by $V$ and more (by definition of a subspace it is a subset of $V$).

Comment: Ok, I think I'm confused regarding the definition of a spanning set. So a spanning set must be identical to the space it spans? It can't have any additional vectors that aren't in the space, although it contains all vectors that are in the space?

Comment: Yes that is accurate